# Is it possible to run queries on 200GB data on mongodb with 16GB RAM?

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I am trying to run a simple query to find number of all records with a particular value using:

> db.ColName.find({id_c:1201}).count()

I have 200GB of data. When I run this query, mongodb takes up all the RAM and my system starts lagging. After an hour of futile waiting, I give up without getting any results.

What can be the issue here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the right approach in the *NoSQL* world isn't trying to perform a full query like that, but accumulate stats overtime.

For example, you should have a collection *stats* with arbitrary objects which should own a *kind* or *id* property that can take a value like `"totalUserCount"`. Whenever you add an user, you also update this count.

This way you'll get **instant** results. It's just getting a property value in a small collection of stats.

BTW, this slowness should be originated by querying objects by a non-indexed property in your collection. [Try to index `id_c` and probably you'll get quicker results.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall look into this.

Comment: @stkusr1234 No problem. Try the indexing approach before the other one, because you know that Mongo doesn't implement multi-document atomic transactions, and if something goes wrong, maybe the `"totalUserCount"` property mightn't reflect the actual count of objects... :(

Comment: Yes, the problem is the data has already been imported so I will be able to follow first approach after I get new data. But I will try to index the data and hope all goes well. I am new to mongodb so didn't really know how things work ^^'

Answer (score 0):

That amount of data can easily be managed by MySQL, MSSQL or Oracle with the given hardware specification. You don't need a NoSQL database for that, NoSQL databases are made for much larger storing needs which actually require lots of hardware (RAM, harddisks) to be efficient.

You need to define an index to read that id and use a normal SQL database.